# Metrix row col wise using JavaScript . who can help me with this.?

Tags: javascript, frontend

**Input**: Row-2,Col-2

OutPut:

1  3

2  4

**Input**: Row-3,Col-3

OutPut:

1  4  7

2  5  8

3  6  9

**Input**: Row-4,Col-4

OutPut:

1  5  9   13

2  6  10  14

3  7  11  14

4  8  12  15

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem?

Comment: Do you want to print this output based on the given input?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fongLrhc/1/   : I tried here, but that not how I want.

Comment: I have written the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the following way:

```js
function solve(r, c) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
        let start = i;
        let array = [];
        for (let j = 1; j <= c; j++) {
            array.push(start);
            start += r;
        }
        console.log([...array])
    }
}

solve(4, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
function createCube(row, col) {
  var arr=new Array(row);
  for(var i=0; i<row; i++) {
    arr[i]=new Array(col);
  }
  for(var i=0; i<row; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<col; j++) {
        arr[i][j]=(i+1)+(j*row);
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

createCube(3,4);
// [[1,4,7,10],[2,5,8,11],[3,6,9,12]]

createCube(4,4);
// [[1,5,9,13],[2,6,10,14],[3,7,11,15],[4,8,12,16]]

createCube(4,5);
// [[1,5,9,13,17],[2,6,10,14,18],[3,7,11,15,19],[4,8,12,16,20]]
```